# PHP forwarding post data to the login page after registration

Tags: php, post, redirect, file-get-contents

I am trying to post data to the login page using the username and password hash generated in the registration page. I had this working but for the life of me cannot figure out why it has stopped.

Basically the code will redirect the user to be automatically logged in if registration was successful. However, the code is also used in an admin panel, so users can be added and be returned to the user management screen.

```
    if (isset($_GET['redirect'])){
        if (isset($_GET['login'])){
            if($_GET['login'] == "true"){
                    // So we can log users automatically after registering
                $post = http_build_query(
                    array(
                        "username" => $username,
                        "password" => $password
                    )
                );
                $context = stream_context_create(
                    array(
                        "http"=>array(
                            "method" => "POST",
                            "header" => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                            "content" => $post
                        )
                    )
                );
                // testing shows that the code gets this far...
                // but does not send the following... instead it skips this


                $page = file_get_contents('http://example.com/login.php?redirect='.$_GET['redirect'], false, $context);
            }
        }
        header('Location: ' . $_GET['redirect']);

        echo('<p><a href="'.$_GET['redirect'] . '">Back to where you were...</a></p>');

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you must provide just password, not its hash code.

Or (if at this point plain password is inaccessible) you can extend login script. It must support some other condition to logging user in - condition where doesn't need to plain password - it can take password's hash, for example. Or place code that marks user as logged in in the separate accessible place and perform it after registration without going to the original login page.

Comment: Thanks for the point on using the password instead of the hash. That is absolute right my login script takes a password not a hash.
However, the file_get_contents is still being skipped.

I am gonna try and see if I can make the user log-in within the registration page... Hopefully it works.

Comment: I just created the user session instead of attempting to send the data to the login page. Thank you.